# Why is my Footer not staying at bottom in Gatsby Site?

Tags: css, gatsby

So I wrapped my content in the layout component and all my other pages push the footer to the bottom because the content is bigger than the actual screen. However, I have one page that has less content and now my footer is awkwardly in the middle if I view it on a bigger height screen.

So here is my footer css

```
      export const FooterContainer = styled.div`
        background-color: #101522;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
      `
```

My layout div css

```
 .layout {
   padding-bottom: 160px;
   position: relative;
 }
```

My layout component

```
           return (
          <>
            <Sidebar isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle} />
            <Navbar toggle={toggle} />
            <div className="layout">
              <main>{children}</main>
              <Footer />
            </div>
          </>
        )
      }
```

Then in my page where my footer isn't sticking to the bottom this is my code

```
             <Layout>
          <div className="resource__container">
            <h1 className="post__heading">
              Here are some resources to learn web development
            </h1>
            <Posts posts={posts} key={posts.id} />
          </div>
        </Layout>
```

So here is a pic showing what is happening

The top black bar is the Navbar

The red section is my `.resource__container`

The white space below that is the `padding-bottom: 160px` from the `.layout <div>`

Then the last black space is the `footer`

After that it's just `<main>` but technically nothing there, so I don't why it isn't sticking to the bottom

[image]

Comment: Is your main page set to be 100% height?

Comment: I tried to add that, but then my footer would rise up on mobile screen and ruin my blog post design, so not sure what I did wrong there

Answer (score 1):

Given a HTML structure like:

```
<body>
  <header>…</header>
  <main>…</main>
  <footer>…</footer>
</body>
```

The solution to stick the footer at the bottom is using flexbox:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}
```

The key is the `min-height: 100vh` as well as `flex: 1` of the `main` tag.

Useful resources:

- https://dev.to/mokkapps/sticky-footer-in-gatsbyjs-using-flexbox-5162
- https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/
- https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/